# How to inspect instanceKlass in hotspot after jdk 8?

Tags: jvm-hotspot, metaspace

Before jdk8, the instanceKlass objects is put in the PermGen area, but now PermGen is replaced by Metaspace and Metaspace is based on native space. Then the question comes, on jdk 7 , you can inspect the vm objects by HSDB, but now the instanceKlass object is not reachable by HSDB, for example, I cannot find where to inspect the ConstantPoolCache.